# SQL expression for largest number in Table

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.4, personal-geodatabase

With "select by attributes" I would like to select the largest number in a column of an attribute table. How would be the SQL expression for that?

I don't want to select it by hand, because I will use it later in a python script (arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()).

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 and the files are within a Personal-Geodatabase.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the exact software you are using, and the storage format of the data (if database, which one, and what version)

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [ESRIs help page](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008936), the Select By Attributes dialog would look something like this:

[image]

Sorry, forgot about the "not by hand part". Here is a python snip using the [SelectLayerByAttribute_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) tool:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view="test", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause="[Area2] IN (SELECT MAX([Area2]) FROM test)")
```

Check out the `Subqueries` section of the [SQL reference page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

select max(col_name) from table;
or
select * from table where col_name=(select max(col_name) from table);

Comment: it seems like these codes don't work. They somehow aren't readable...